# Redirect All Unused Link on a subdomain to a domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect all the unused link in my subdomain.olddomain.com to newdomain.com
i tried this but it doesn't seem to work for subdomain

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^subdomain\.olddomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I manage to make the code below but the issue is it does not redirect or catch all the unused like. It only redirects the root and returns page error when accessing unused link(e.g. tag) An example url  look like below (OsCommerce)

**sub.domain.com/product_info.php?products_id=999&osCsid=29f8a9504d1c4de90a1a1e4106344280**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.newdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Additional Info:
What I am trying to do is redirect all the link coming from subdomain.olddomain.com to newdomain.com so for example when someone visit subdomain.olddomain.com/tags/vanilla or subdomain.olddomain.com/product_info.php?products_id=999&osCsid=29f8a9504d1c4de90a1a1e4106344280m they will automatically be redirected to newdomain.com , the newdomain.com is located in another server server

Comment: What does `doesn't seem to work` actually mean? Could you add an example of a URL that doesn't work for you, with what you expect vs what you actually get?

Comment: The other link are not being catch. i updated my question please check

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) (emphasis mine):

> Per-directory Rewrites
>
> - The rewrite engine may be used in .htaccess files and in  sections, with some additional complexity.
> - To enable the rewrite engine in this context, you need to set "RewriteEngine On" and "Options FollowSymLinks" must be enabled. If
>     your administrator has disabled override of FollowSymLinks for a
>     user's directory, then you cannot use the rewrite engine. This
>     restriction is required for security reasons.
> - When using the rewrite engine in .htaccess files the per-directory prefix (which always is the same for a specific directory) is
>     automatically removed for the RewriteRule pattern matching and
>     automatically added after any relative (not starting with a slash or
>     protocol name) substitution encounters the end of a rule set. See the
>     RewriteBase directive for more information regarding what prefix will
>     be added back to relative substitutions.
> - If you wish to match against the full URL-path in a per-directory (htaccess) RewriteRule, use the %{REQUEST_URI} variable in a
>     RewriteCond.
> - **The removed prefix always ends with a slash, meaning the matching occurs against a string which never has a leading slash. Therefore, a
>     Pattern with ^/ never matches in per-directory context.**
> - Although rewrite rules are syntactically permitted in  and  sections (including their regular expression counterparts),
>     this should never be necessary and is unsupported. A likely feature to
>     break in these contexts is relative substitutions.

The .htaccess-file is per-directory context, so your rule will never ever match anything. Your rule should look like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^subdomain\.olddomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$         http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This is assuming that newdomain.com does not use this .htaccess file, as that would cause an infinite redirect.

Comment: This rule will: Redirect **all** urls **except** urls that are to the domain name `subdomain.olddomain.com` **to** `http://www.newdomain.com/what-ever/the-old?url=was`. I have the sneaking suspicion that you don't want to exclude any urls, and that your new domain is on a different server. If the new domain isn't on a new server, then you want to exclude the new domain name, not the old one.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. What I am trying to do is redirect all the link coming from subdomain.olddomain.com to newdomain.com so for example subdomain.olddomain.com/tags/vanilla , subdomain.olddomain.com/product_info.php?products_id=999&osCsid=29f8a9504d1c4de90a1a1e4106344280 will redirect to the same url which is newdomain.com , the newdomain is located in a different server